# why console in asp.net mvc5 doesn't run all of commands and this problem does not end?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, database-migration

the console in Asp.net mvc5(visual studio 2015) doesn't  run all of commands!
It should be noted that the console commands in the previous operating system(windows 10) worked well for this project
this is that error:
[image]

I replaced the packages even once.
this is new meassage in console but i can't install new package!
[image]
can you help me to fix this problem?
'Thank you in advance for your help'

Comment: What have you tried so far? What dependencies from EF have you installed? It can be an issue with the missing package with tools for entity framework or just problem with the package manager. Hard to say without additional information.

Comment: I really don't know the reason for this problem! Because I didn't install a new package or delete a package @kyziur

Comment: Ok. In the topic is information about the previous operating system Win10. What operating system is used right now? Did you try do restore all dependencies in project? Is project passing build step? Did you try using powershell to invoke this command?

Comment: now i use win 10 again,yes restored all dependencies in project.i don't have enough information about powershell! @kyziur

Comment: look at to this new meassage for me in console, i edited my question with that @kyziur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of the interference of the packages.
First deleted QRCODER Package then run commands in console!
then install it again.